# Direct Optimisation - How to Create Time Efficient Study

Tags: mechanical-engineering, ansys, optimal-control, thermal-expansion

I made a simulation of this cylinder that is being suspended mid air and held up by 8 rods, 4 on top and 4 on the bottom. The entire model is cooled to 15K

I managed to find the forces required for 6 of the rods to have a safety factor of above 1 as pictured below (green being above 1):
[image]

The two rods in red have a safety factor of less than 1. All rods have a parametrised force so I would like to know how to create a design study to get all of the rods to be above 1 or at least all have the same safety factor under 1. Basically, I am only interested in changing the forces that are applied to the rods.

I've tried an Adaptive Multiple Objective with the goals of all rods having a safety factor above 1 but it didn't produce any meaningful results.

Comment: Time efficient study or safety factor?

Comment: Safety factor haha. Time would be desirable too

Comment: Thermal, so heated by welding torch or what? local or along complete length? or just at the fixing point to the object?

Comment: The entire model is being cooled to 15K.

Comment: You should considered editing your question so that the conditions are clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out about Response Surfaces and using all the points that I already created, created a Response Surface Optimization which let me easily find the answer without a significant amount more computation.